# convert Integer to int

Tags: java, integer, int

I have an Integer value of variable as below:

```
Integer programNumber= ........
```

I took the program number as Integer type. However in my other class, I want to check whether this variable, programNumber, equals variable which is the type of int.

To sum up, I want to convert the variable of the of Integer to int primitive value.
I used `programno.intValue()` but it doesn't work.
Thanks in advance.

I have a two class, BasvuruKisi and Program. the code snippet is below:

```
BasvuruKisi bsvkisi = (BasvuruKisi) (this.getHibernateTemplate().find("from BasvuruKisi bsv where bsv.basvuruNo=?", basvuruNumaralari.get(i))).get(0);

        if (bsvkisi != null) {
            int yetkiVarmi = 0;
            Integer programno= bsvkisi.getProgramId();
           List array = 

this.getHibernateTemplate().find("from Program p where p.id=?", programno.intValue());
```

but

```
this.getHibernateTemplate().find("from Program p where p.id=?", programno.intValue());
```

this one doesn't work. return firstly, no table or view is available despite available and then returns null pointer exception. 
thanks

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it doesn't work"?  What goes wrong?

Comment: "I used `programno.intValue()` but it doesn't work." That should work. What do you mean with "it doesn't work"? Do you get an error? What is the error?

Comment: Can you give a little code snippet instead of just .....

Comment: You should have used `programNumber.intValue()`

Comment: So.  (1) Why did you only post a tiny fraction of the relevant information originally?  (2)  What is the value of `bsvkisi.getProgramId();` for the Basvurukisi that was returned by the first query?

Comment: bsvkisi.getProgramId(); is taken successfully. Integer value 22. now, it is working. and intValue() is working surprisingly now. but return null pointer exception now although the programNumber is valid. I will communicate database administrator. and inform you if I have solved the problem. Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The variable name in the initialization block says programNumber, but the variable in the method call is programno. Which is it?

Using the wrong variable name shouldn't give you a null pointer exception, unless you have another variable named programno defined somewhere.

Whatever the variable name is, make sure you initialize it before you get the intValue.

Comment: Firstly, it says no table or view available although it is available. After that, it says java.lang.NullPointerException. However, the Program table has a primary key column.In Program table, the column of proimary key is such. PROGRAM_ID NUMBER No  1

Comment: @kaan this sounds like a database accessibility issue. What does your query look like? Are you able to login to the console and get the data you want with the same query?

Comment: @Chad, Most probably you are right. I will communicate with the database administrator. I f problem doesn't relate to database, I will return here to take your help. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Validate programNumber is null or not?

If the value is null, it throws Exception.

```
Integer programNumber= null;
System.out.println(programNumber.intValue());
```